# What is the hex value of (1 << 27)?

Tags: c++, c, bit-shift

Just started an embedded systems course with very little background knowledge. Could someone explain how I would go about answering this? It seems simple enough and I can't access my lecture slides yet.

Comment: what's (1 << 1)  ?  Repeat....  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Comment: it is shifting 1 to left 27 bits

Answer (score 9):

Without any programming...

1 << 27 is, in binary, a 1 followed by 27 zeros:

1000000000000000000000000000

To convert to hex, first group the value into 4 bit groups, padding on the left with extra zeros, if necessary:

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Convert each group of 4 bits into the corresponding hex equivalent.

```
   8    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Or, without the spaces, and with the traditional '0x' prefix:

0x8000000

Comment: simple explanation: in the binary universe of zeros 1 is moved 27 positions left from its current position

Answer (score 4):

Just try it:

```
int main() {
    long l = (1 << 27);
    printf ("%x\n", l);

    return 0;
}
```

The output, btw, is `8000000`.

Answer (score 3):

The bit pattern need to represent `1` has all zero bits but the last bit. The expression `1 << 27` evaluates to a value in which the last bit is moved 27 places and the right is filled with zeros.

You can get to that value step by step:

```
 1     :  00000001
 1 << 7:  10000000  (0x80)
 1 << 15: 10000000 00000000   (0x8000)
 1 << 23: 10000000 00000000 00000000  (0x800000)
 1 << 27: 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000  (0x08000000)
```